# Swift iOS - Overlay text onto PDF with PDFKit and UI

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, pdfkit, uigraphicscontext

I'm working in Swift 5 and on iOS.  I'm trying to overlay text onto a current PDF I have.  I'm essentially porting code I made from an app for macOS.  This is the code from the Mac version:

```
func executeContext(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) {
    
    // Confirm there is a document there
    if let doc: PDFDocument = PDFDocument(url: srcURL) {
        
        // Create a document, get the first page, and set the size of the page
        let page: PDFPage = doc.page(at: 0)!
        var mediaBox: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 792, height: 612)
        
        // This is where the magic happens.  Create the drawing context on the PDF
        let context = CGContext(dstURL as CFURL, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)
        let graphicsContext = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: context!, flipped: false)
        NSGraphicsContext.current = graphicsContext
        
        context!.beginPDFPage(nil)
        
        // Draws the PDF into the context
        page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context!)
        
        // Parse and Draw Text on the context
        //drawText()
        
        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 72)
        ]
        let text = "I'm a PDF!"
        text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attributes)
        
        context!.saveGState()
        
        context!.restoreGState()
        
        context!.endPDFPage()
        NSGraphicsContext.current = nil
        context?.closePDF()
    }
}
```

The `drawText()` function did most of the text overlaying that was needed, but I put another "draw "method below it to test it out.

I'm understandably getting an error `Cannot find 'NSGraphicsContext' in scope` since NSGraphicsContext doesn't exist on iOS.  I've tried to find an equivalent translation with UIGraphicsPDFRenderer or UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData, and using some code from a [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit), I was able to create a new PDF and place text on it with the below code:

```
func createDocument(url: URL) -> Data {
    
    //let pdfData = try? Data.init(contentsOf: url)
    
    // 1
    let pdfMetaData = [
        kCGPDFContextCreator: "Timecard App",
        kCGPDFContextAuthor: "Timecard App"
    ]
    let format = UIGraphicsPDFRendererFormat()
    format.documentInfo = pdfMetaData as [String: Any]
    
    // 2
    let pageWidth = 8.5 * 72.0
    let pageHeight = 11 * 72.0
    let pageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight)
    
    // 3
    let renderer = UIGraphicsPDFRenderer(bounds: pageRect, format: format)
    
    // 4
    let data = renderer.pdfData { (context) in
        // 5
        context.beginPage()
        // 6
        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 72)
        ]
        let text = "I'm a PDF!"
        text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attributes)
    }
    
    return data
}
```

...but I couldn't find a way to load in current PDF "data" to the renderer and then draw from there. Does anyone have any suggestions on the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is possible solution - actually you just need to operate with CoreGraphics context directly, set current, flip transform, etc. (style and conventions of original code preserved).

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

[image: demo]

```
func executeContext(at srcURL: URL, to dstURL: URL) {
    
    // Confirm there is a document there
    if let doc: PDFDocument = PDFDocument(url: srcURL) {
        
        // Create a document, get the first page, and set the size of the page
        let page: PDFPage = doc.page(at: 0)!
        var mediaBox: CGRect = page.bounds(for: .mediaBox)
    
        // This is where the magic happens.  Create the drawing context on the PDF
        let context = CGContext(dstURL as CFURL, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context!)
        context!.beginPDFPage(nil)

        // Draws the PDF into the context
        page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context!)
        
        let flipVertical: CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform(a: 1, b: 0, c: 0, d: -1, tx: 0, ty: mediaBox.size.height)
        context!.concatenate(flipVertical)

        let attributes = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 72)
        ]
        let text = "I'm a PDF!"
        text.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), withAttributes: attributes)
        
        context!.endPDFPage()
        context?.closePDF()

        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks very much!  I only needed to change the media box line to work with my specific pdf.

Comment: @Asperi This has worked great for me. I have a multiple page PDF that I want to edit. How would I go about adding the additional pages? When I try and add a 2nd page it overwrites the first.

Comment: @SteveHancocks Did you find any solution for multiple pages?

Comment: @YasheedMohammed Yes, see the answer below.

Comment: @YasheedMohammed, this should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498974/12299030 - another my answer for multi-page PDF on macOS, almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

Edit additional pages using the following function

```
// add a new page
    func addPage(number: Int){
        // index is one less than document page number
        let index = number - 1
        context.endPDFPage()
        if let page = document.page(at: index) {
            context.beginPDFPage(nil)
            page.draw(with: .mediaBox, to: context)
            context.concatenate(flipVertical)
        }
    }
```

Where document is the PDF document you wish to edit.

Then start editing that new page. The X and Y coordinates reset to 0,0 again for the new page.

Comment: @YasheedMohammed easier to see the solution in code.